# iOS: Anyone had an App rejected for ignoring kCLErrorDenied

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager

The documentation for CLLocationManagerDelegate locationManager:didFailWithError, says:

If the user denies your application’s use of the location service, this method reports a kCLErrorDenied error. Upon receiving such an error, you should stop the location service.

However, if you simply ignore the error, you don't get any more location updates anyway. Also ignoring the error has the advantage that if the user goes to Settings and enables Location Services for your app, the next time your app come to foreground the location service updates start again.

So I plan on ignoring all errors from locationManager:didFailWithError unless someone can spot any problems or thinks the app will get rejected.

One problem might be power usage, but I would think once the error has happened there is no extra power being used, as Im not getting any updates or anything.

My fallback is to re-enable updates when i come to foreground. Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't handle kCLErrorDenied until a recently and had no issue with Apple. There shouldn't be any issues with it because your app just behaves as if there's no location services. However, you should handle it and provide some instructions to the user to turn on Location Services especially if Location Services are a major part of your app.